# SQL Statement to name columns based on values in other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, case

```
id | type | email
__________________

1  | ls  | example@gmail.com
_________________

1  | sp  | example@yahoo.com
_________________

2  | sp  | example@live.com
```

I am trying to create a SQL command something like the following (pseudo):

SELECT id as 'ID', email where type = 'ls' as 'LS Email', email where type = 'sp' as 'SP Email'
FROM table;

I have tried using CASE also but can't seem to get it working properly. The goal is to return something like the following:

```
ID | LS Email         | SP Email
________________________________
1 | example@gmail.com | 
1 |                   | example@yahoo.com
2 |                   | example@live.com
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` expressions like so:

```
select
    id,
    case when type 'ls' then email end ls_email,
    case when type 'sp' then email end sp_email
from mytable
```

If you want both values for the same `id` on the same row (which is not what you showed in your expected results), then you can aggregate on top of that:

```
select
    id,
    max(case when type 'ls' then email end) ls_email,
    max(case when type 'sp' then email end) sp_email
from mytable
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, max(case when type = 'ls' then email end) as ls,
       max(case when type = 'sp' then email end) as sp
from t
group by id;
```

If you can have duplicates, then you might want to use `group_concat()` so you get all the values:

```
select id, 
       group_concat(case when type = 'ls' then email end) as ls,
       group_concat(case when type = 'sp' then email end) as sp
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: The desired output doesn't look like it needs the agg part, btw